# Jprofiler - how to collect default probes data with Java api?

Tags: java, api, jdbc, jprofiler

I'm struggling to find how to trigger default probes with Jprofiler Java API.
Do you have any examples on how-to do it ?
The sample folder have only examples of new probe creation.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the Controller API in the profiled code, or are you using ConnectionFactory to open your own connection to the profiling agent?

Comment: I'm using ConnectionFactory (from example folder provided).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call

```
connection.recordPayload(...)
```

See the Javadoc for that method in `com.jprofiler.api.platform.connection.Connection`.

A general note on using ConnectionFactory: If you just do offline profiling and want to save snapshots for later analysis, use the Controller API and profile with the ",offline" parameter appended to the -agentpath command. The remote integration wizard will help to to set up offline profiling.

ConnectionFactory is only useful of you want to write a program that requires profiling data.

Comment: Issue with my code was - that I was using 7.2.3 version of Jprofier and API, but this function was introduced only in 8.0.6